# Under what conditions does FinancialData return a ::notent message?

Tags: curated-data, finance, free-form-input

I tried retrieving `FinancialData` for a few companies but when I tried doing it for NTDOY, I couldn't. As of 25/12/2012, querying

```
 FinancialData["PK:NTDOY"]
```

yields

> FinancialData::notent: PK:NTDOY is not a known entity, class, or tag for FinancialData. Use FinancialData[] for a list of entities.

However, this is weird for two reasons. Firstly, `PK:NTDOY` is included in the list of financial instruments Mathematica supposedly has data for:

```
 FinancialData["*NTD*"]
```

yields

```
 {"JK:INTD", "NASDAQ:GKNTD", "NASDAQ:UNTD", "PK:ANTD", "PK:NTDMF", "PK:NTDOF", "PK:NTDOY"}
```

Secondly, if I try using free-form input, e.g.

> = NTDOY price from 25 December 2011 to 25 December 2012

I get the same (notent) output; on the other hand, if I click on the orange "Show all results" plus symbol, I get a WA-like tab filled with meaningful data, even though sometimes Mathematica crashes while computing.

So my question is: what does `FinancialData` truly mean when it states that something is not "known"? Is this a software bug or is it simply that more data is available to WolframAlpha than is to Mathematica?

(I'm using Mathematica 8.0.1.0, by the way.)

Comment: I think it's currently listed "NTDOY" without the PK.  On [Google](http://www.google.com/finance?cid=685139), it's PINK:NTDOY, but on [Yahoo](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bc?s=NTDOF.PK,NTDOY.PK) it says it's been renamed.  Try `FinancialData["NTDOY"]`, which works for me.  I don't know why it still lists "PK:NTODY" as a valid entity.

Comment: The list of instruments given by FinancialData["*"] isn't updated very frequently. In fact, I believe it would only be updated when the paclets are updated. If the availability of a ticker has recently changed, then it may be on the list and no longer work. The best way to see what kind of information is available is to really just look at Yahoo Finance.

Comment: @Searke, that looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NTDOY** is the Nasdaq ticker for the Nintendo ADR. Once it's traded on an American stock exchange you don't need to define the stock exchange previously (i.e., you don't need to use `PK:` before the NTDOY ticker).

So, the only thing you have to do is to use

```
FinancialData["NTDOY"]
```

and *Mathematica* will retrieve the current price:

> 11.79

**EDITED**

You have to be careful when using non-American stock exchanges... For instance, try to find the Petrobras stock on *Mathematica* (ticker = PETR4):

```
FinancialData["*PETR4*", "Lookup"]
```

and the answer will be

> {SA:PETR4}

But, in fact you can use two different tickers for the same stock! See:

```
FinancialData["SA:PETR4"]
```

> 19.39

or you can also try

```
FinancialData["PETR4.SA"]
```

> 19.39

So the results are the same! I mean, the `SA:` **prefix** is the same as the `.SA` **suffix** for the Sao Paulo Stock Exchange (Brazil), although it's not documented by *Mathematica*.

I think this is also true for other stock exchanges.