# Is FinancialData for India available?

Tags: curated-data, finance

```
FinancialData["IndiaNSE", "Members"] // Shallow
```

gives

```
{"^CNXIT", "^CRSLDX", "^CRSMID", "NS:20MICRONS", "NS:3IINFOTEC", \
"NS:3MINDIA", "NS:526015", "NS:AARTIDRUG", "NS:AARTIIND", \
"NS:AARVEEDEN", <<1432>>}
```

But when I query

```
FinancialData["NS:20MICRONS"]
```

I get the following error

```
 FinancialData::notent: NS:20MICRONS is not a known entity, class, or tag for
  FinancialData. Use FinancialData[] for a list of entities. >>
```

Interestingly I tried the same query on Wolfram Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FinancialData[%22NS%3A20MICRONS%22]

I got this **Assuming 20MICRONS | Use 533022 instead**

I tried

```
FinancialData["MB:533022"]
```

and I got the same error!

Is this expected ?

Comment: It appears to be a bug. I am a Brazilian, and I am able to access Brazilian data. As one of the datasources for FinancialData is finance.yahoo.com and beyond that, the exchanges are abbreviated as Yahoo abbreviate them, I used to believe that if you can access this address http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=20MICRONS.NS
then FinancialData should report a valid answer for `FinancialData["NS:20MICRONS"]`. Take a look at this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16944/under-what-conditions-does-financialdata-return-a-notent-message

Comment: bug - hmm! 

I looked at the link provided above. Sounds like the support must have been discontinued.

I tried using 20MICRONS.NS - it does not work

Comment: Also found this link [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/problem-with-financial-data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/problem-with-financial-data) where the data was not working since its source (Yahoo) discontinued to support

Comment: My bad. @ram got it right. I am only adding another link that could be included in Mathematica documentation as well.
It is a list from Yahoo! of the exchanges and the data Yahoo! can provide.
http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_FIN&locale=en_US&id=SLN2310
Here you can see that for National Stock Exchange of India the data are only real-time and for signed in users.

Comment: Vitaly Kaurov's answer to the [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9540/) you linked works if you substitute "NS:20MICRONS price history" for "^DJI price history".